# How to add more information to title slide

Tags: hyperref, titles

I have the following section of TeX:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\author{My Name}
\title{My Title}
\date{The Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
\maketitle
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

If I try to add anything else to the title slide it is pushed on to the next slide. How can I add my twitter name and a link to my github account to the title page?

Comment: Can you include also the preamble of your document such that we can compile and see the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\title`, `\author` and `\date` literally just stores its contents in `\@title`, `\@author` and `\@date`. So, you can just store more stuff in any one of them if you'd like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{slides}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\author{\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\centering
  My Name \\
  \small Twitter: \href{http://www.twitter.com/whocares}{@whocares} \\[3pt]
  Github: \href{https://github.com/whocares/repository}{Github Repository}}}
\title{My Title}
\date{The Date}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
\maketitle
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

The formatting of the hyperlinks via `\hypersetup`, as well as the layout can be changed.

Comment: I tried this, the compilation never ends. Removing `\parbox` it works

Comment: @Nisba: `\author` makes its way into the PDF document properties. Sometimes you may have to issue `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` to distinguish between content - `<TeX>` - set within the PDF, and that which ends up in the PDF document properties - `<PDF>`. In that sense, you'll use the `\parbox` setup as part of `<TeX>`, while removing all (La)TeX-related content for what you want in `<PDF>`.

Comment: @Werner, how to insert some definition inside a slide ? For example, `\begin{defn} ... \end{defn}` is a latex command to make a definition inside a slide. There are others more e.g., `\begin{thm}....\end{thm}`. How to run such commands ?

Comment: @MAS: You need to define them yourself. How, for example, is the `defn` environment defined? In a similar way you could define `thm`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
\author[My name]{My name \\ {\ttfamily myemail@email.com}}
\date[The date]{The date \\ {\smaller Name of the conference}}
...
```

**Disclaimer:** This solution applies to the `beamer` package. I'm unaware of the behaviour of the `slides` package.